# SwiftUI - View dismissing itself upon rotation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that displays images. When tapping on an image, it launches a full screen version where the user can pinch/zoom. However, when rotating the device from portrait to landscape in that view, the view dismisses itself. Oddly there are some images where the view will not dismiss itself and work properly. However, for most images the view automatically dismisses upon rotation. I should note that this happens whether it is presented as a full screen or sheet.

```
struct GalleryGridView: View {
    @ObservedObject var galleryVM:GalleryPublisher
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100)),
            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100)),
            GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100))
        ]
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(galleryVM.object.artworks ?? [], id:\.self) { artwork in
                ImageView(path: artwork.asset?.path)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .id(artwork.id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ImageView:View {
        var path:String?
        
        @State private var image:UIImage?
        @State private var gotoFullScreen = false
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                if let image = image {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            gotoFullScreen = true
                        }
                } else {
                    Rectangle()
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $gotoFullScreen, content: {
                FullImageView(image: image!)
            })
            .onAppear {
                guard let path = path else {print("Missing image path");return}
                NetworkManager.shared.downloadImage(urlStr: path) { image in
                    self.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct FullImageView: View {
    var image:UIImage

    var body: some View {
        PhotoDetailView(image: image)
    }
}

struct PhotoDetailView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let image: UIImage

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let view = PDFView()
        view.document = PDFDocument()
        guard let page = PDFPage(image: image) else {return view }
        view.document?.insert(page, at: 0)
        view.autoScales = true
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: Take the columns out of the body and use an id instead of self in the loop

Comment: This needs a [mre], but my assumption is that it relates to the grid being re-rendered on rotation (although that doesn't explain the intermittent behavior). I'd move the `sheet` presentation out of the `ImageView` and up to the parent view's level.

Comment: @loremipsum - Tried both, but same behavior unfortunately.

Comment: @jnpdx - This worked, thank you! Feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: Since I don't have a concrete explanation (and can't reproduce it), I'm going to decline to answer, but feel free to add it as an answer yourself.

Comment: @jnpdx - The part making it difficult to explain is why it would work for some images but not others. This was very consistent as to the images. Otherwise I would be inclined to think that the struct is getting broken down and moving the call up to the parent was kept. To the extent that had any merit, it is lost with the aforementioned comment about the images.  A SwiftUI mystery while not surprising is hard to swallow.